# How vb.net split string

Tags: vb.net

I have a file txt file that  values  i want split after value "accession_number="  and before value "&token"

example Values in  text file :

10.0.0.6:80/ImageSuite/Web/Worklist/DICOMViewer.aspx?patient_id=5049885&study_uid=201702060824&accession_number=20170206082802&token

10.0.0.6:80/ImageSuite/Web/Worklist/DICOMViewer.aspx?patient_id=4409276&study_uid=201702060826&accession_number=20170206083002&token

10.0.0.6:80/ImageSuite/Web/Worklist/DICOMViewer.aspx?patient_id=4402764&study_uid=201702060801&accession_number=20170206080416&token

10.0.0.6:80/ImageSuite/Web/Worklist/DICOMViewer.aspx?patient_id=4402537&study_uid=201702060837&accession_number=20170206084025&token

example values after proccess :
20170206082802 
20170206083002
20170206080416
20170206084025

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by reading all lines, and then based on the lines you can execute following code (assuming the file you want to read is located at C:\test.txt)

```
dim results = from line in File.ReadAllLines("C:\test.txt") _
              where not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) _
              from field in line.Split("&") _
              where field.StartsWith("accession_number=") _
              select field.Split("=")(1)
for each result in results
    Console.WriteLine(result)
next
```

This will use as an input all lines, and then for the lines that are not empty, it will split using `&` and then it checks if that field startswith the accession_number, if it does, it splits by `=` to return the second item in the array.

As an extra explanation:

```
from line in File.ReadAllLines("C:\test.txt")
```

while evaluate every single line in the file

```
' input eg: 10.0.0.6:80/ImageSuite/Web/Worklist/DICOMViewer.aspx?patient_id=5049885&study_uid=201702060824&accession_number=20170206082802&token
where not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( line )
```

will exclude all empty lines (or lines that exist only of whitespaces)

```
from field in line.Split("&")
```

will split every found line into an array of strings using the `&` as a separator

```
 ' field eg: accession_number=20170206082802
 where field.StartsWith("accession_number=")
```

will exclude all fields that do not start with `accession_number=`

```
 select field.Split("=")(1)
 ' result sample: 20170206082802
```

will return for any matches the part after `=`

A full example you can find on this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/06cI5w). It uses a slightly different method to read from stream, simply because in that environment, I cannot provide a dummy file, however, it should do the trick

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when you can use either [**`File.ReadAllLines()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) or iterate [**`StreamReader.ReadLine()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @VisualVincent That's true, didn't really think about that :) However, that wasn't really part of the question, I just added the fiddle as a full example. I updated the sample now though. Also, your example does a similar thing, in mine he just has to replace from where the stream is coming. Though I might have been overthinking it ;)

Comment: I know mine does a similar thing, but I mainly provided an alternate method. -- I wrote the previous comment because you can save yourself some code and loops by using built-in methods instead of writing new methods doing essentially the same thing.

Comment: Although it is not a part of the question it's still good to for an answer to utilize good practice (not saying what you're doing is necessarily _bad_, but parts of your code can be replaced by built-in methods :).

Comment: @VisualVincent Sure, that's a good idea, I updated the code in the answer, and pointed out why I use different methods in the dotnetfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can read each line into an array of strings using [**`File.ReadAllLines()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) and then iterate over that and parse the information using a [**`Regex`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
'Declare the Regex.
Dim Parser As New Regex("(?<=accession_number\=)\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

'Read the file's lines into an array of strings.
Dim Lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\test.txt")

'Iterate over the array.
For Each Line As String In Lines
    Dim m As Match = Parser.Match(Line) 'Match the pattern.
    If m.Success = True Then 'Was the match successful?
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value) 'Print the matched value.
    End If
Next
```

**Online test: http://ideone.com/VU5Iyj**

Regex pattern explanation:

```
(?<=accession_number\=)\d+

(?<=                      => Match must be preceded by...
    accession_number\=    => ..."accession_number=".
)                         => End of preceding capture group.
\d+                       => Match one or more numerical characters.
```